# Identifying Outliers in a Set of 1-D Binary Vectors in Python

Tags: python, scipy, dbscan, mahalanobis

I am investigating the optimal way to identify outlier vectors when you have m 1-D binary vectors with n features, for example:

```
a =[[1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]]
```

In my case n and m are in the 100's.  I would like to identify which vectors are outliers in the population.  I have found some information using Mahalanobis Distance in SciPy and packages like HDBSCAN (note, I will be clustering these outliers after they are identified to see if there are any further patterns in the outliers).  In both cases the examples are limited, but I also don't know if this the best method to use with binary vectors.  Any advice and examples or references would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by outliers? values other than `0` and `1` ?? Can you provide an example.

Comment: It would be vectors that are outliers.  So, for example, if you added [0,0,0,0,0,0,0] to the set above it might be highlighted as an outlier given that the others have some reasonably equal numbers of 1's and 0's.  In Mahalanobis I believe each vectors is assigned a standard deviation value relative to some reference for the population.

Comment: Mahalanobis in only meaningful for continuous data. Don't use it on binary data.

Comment: The first vector differs from the second in 4 locations, and from the third in 5. I'd say the 0 vector is not more unusual than the first.